# Is blowing air (from lungs) into a water/soap solution changing the liquid into a gas contained in the bubbles?

Tags: solutions

I am teaching an art lesson to second graders. We are going to blow bubbles into a dyed soapy solution and then place the bubbles on paper.  When the dyed bubbles pop, it makes for a great bubbly background to our fish art.

To tie in science, specifically liquids and gas, I'd like to explain the reaction that is happening when we create a bubble.

Also, I'd like to explain what happens to the gas and liquid surrounding the bubble when it pops.

Any SUPER SIMPLE scientific explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no reaction. It's a physical phenomenon. When the bubble pops, the gas inside starts to mix with the gas outside. The liquid splatters. Its movement is governed by air currents, gravity, and the initial trajectory as a result of the pop.

Comment: A bubble is like a balloon made from a soapy film.  A soapy film in a bubble is pressurized under tension like the rubber in an inflated balloon. Balloon rubber is different than soapy film because a soapy film is a liquid and rubber is a solid.  A solid balloon breaking makes a louder noise (pow) than a liquid bubble breaking (pop).          - Most 2nd graders cannot handle abstract concepts; however, they can handle similarities and differences.

Comment: The physics stack exchange may be a better place for this question.  There is a similar question there already.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167312/surface-tension-and-soap-bubbles

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a chemical reaction happening there. What you have is they physical phenomenon of the gas from the lungs getting trapped inside of a film made of soap and water - it is like filling a balloon, but instead of rubber, you have soapy water.

And, as opposed from what you have with rubber, the soap+water film is NOT stable by itself, so after a while it collapses, hence the popping. What happens then is that the gas from the lungs then mixes with the air around.

Comment: The reason bubbles do not last long has mostly to do with weather and climate.  If the climate is foggy the soap film will dilute becoming more like water.  If it is hot and dry, the thin film will evaporate.  If it is windy, the wind will break the bubbles.  If it is after a rainstorm, the wind is still, and it is cool... then bubbles will last plenty long enough to have fun.    ... stability phenomena may be tough for second grader to grasp.